# Resetting animation frame to initial position

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Hi I am using unity3D 2018.3
My game is a 2D animation based game and i am using a single scene to control levels. it is using different panels to show levels.

I have tried the following code but it didn't help me out

```
Animation anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation> ();        
anim["EreaserErease"].time = 0;
```

```
Animation anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation> ();        
anim.Play();
anim.Stop();
```

I want to reset the animation back to the initial frame as I re-enter to the level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 're-entering' the level you mean the level resets then you can use `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);` to reset the scene. Note that you'll have to have put `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` for this to work.

If that's not what you mean then you should probably look into Unity's built in [animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html), from here you can set up paths between different animations and criteria for the transitions. From there you can use `anim.SetBool()` to manage the transitions.

Comment: Actually i am using a single scene and i am not using animator. i want it to happen by Animation Component.

Comment: @HamzaMushtaq you can still reset the scene if you are using a single scene, also I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you could do without using the animator, do you have any particular reason for not wanting to use it?

Comment: Restarting a scene would cause my cloud system to restart as well which is visible on every level. and animator was issuing the same as animation. whenever an animation is playing and I change to the main menu or other panels the animation is at last frame.

Comment: Have you tried an animation transition to itself that is set to run when there is a restart?

Comment: No, I don't know about it.

Comment: Have a look at that link I put in the answer. Create a transition that occurs when a certain boolean is set to true from the animation you want to restart to itself, then in your code set that boolean to true when you want the animation to restart.